# Error when using Robotium+Spoon

Tags: android, robotium, spoon

I have a problem when starting tests via Robotium+Spoon. After several minutes in Spoon's report I see an error:

`Failed to receive adb shell test output within 600000 ms. Test may have timed out, or adb connection to device became unresponsive
com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException`

But my Robotium tests are still working.
Can anybody help to solve this problem or give an advice how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details such as how many devices have you connected? What is the adb version etc? It seems adb is  getting timeout after 10 mins,

Comment: It doesn't depends on connected devices. adb version - 1.0.31 
Have you any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's limitation within spoon. I found in sources that tests must finish within 10 minutes. Look at this [source code](https://github.com/square/spoon/blob/master/spoon-runner/src/main/java/com/squareup/spoon/SpoonDeviceRunner.java#L40)

I'm not sure if it's configurable or not.

Comment: In a new version of Spoon will be --adb-timeout option

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely there are issues from your test scripts or the tested app, but not from Spoon.

This error message is telling you it lost connection with adb more than 10 mins. I have seen it for some times after my test app crashes, so I believe the best way to find the answer is to look up your test log to locate possible exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is one option to set time as per your requirement

Spoon option

```
--adb-timeout       Set maximum execution time per test in seconds (10min default)
```